# Creating a secondary x axis

Tags: c#, mschart

I was given a table that looked a something like this:

```
 Date  |             1/1/13             |             1/8/13             | ...
       |  Group1  |  Group2  |  Group3  |  Group1  |  Group2  |  Group3  | ...
Type1  |     1    |     2    |     3    |     5    |     6    |     7    | ...
Type2  |     6    |     5    |     4    |     4    |     8    |     0    | ...
Type3  |     7    |     8    |     9    |     9    |     3    |     2    | ...
```

My task is to create a graph using MS Chart to represent this data. The table represents tasks (Type1/2/3) that have been completed by a certain group during the week ending in the displayed date. My idea is to create a bar graph first grouped by date then by the group. I would like my x axis to look like the table header above.

I've looked up secondary axis topics, and all I can find are secondary Y axises. This is different from what I desire because it represents a different series on each of the y axises. I would like to be able to represent a single series, but with two x axis labels. Is this even possible? I'm not convinced it is, since data points ca only have two values

```
var chart = new Chart();
chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
var series= new Series("series");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
series.XAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
//Magic secondary axis code    

//Add data points

chart.Series.Add(series);
```

And just for reference, here are the classes I plan on using.

**Classes**

```
public class ChartGroup
{
    public string GroupName
    public int Type1
    public int Type2
    public int Type3
}
public class ChartDate
{
    public DateTime Date
    public List<ChartGroup> GroupData
}
public class Chart
{
    public List<ChartDate> ChartData
}
```

**EDIT:** I do believe it is possible to create such a chart by making a series for each type, and graphing it on an x axis of `Date`. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to have a secondary X axis. Here is an example (it's not exactly what you want to do, but should show you how to use the secondary X axis):

```
DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(2013, 01, 01);
DateTime secondDay = new DateTime(2013, 01, 02);

int[] group1 = new int[6] { 1, 6, 7, 5, 4, 9 };
int[] group2 = new int[6] { 2, 5, 8, 6, 8, 3 };

DateTime[] days = new DateTime[6] { firstDay, firstDay, firstDay, secondDay, secondDay, secondDay};

chart.Series.Add(new Series("Group 1"));

chart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(days, group1);
chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

chart.Series.Add(new Series("Group 2"));
chart.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(days, group2);
chart.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

double start = chart.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
double end = chart.Series[0].Points[chart.Series[0].Points.Count -1].XValue;
double half = (start + end) / 2;

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.CustomLabels.Add(start, end, "General Label", 0, LabelMarkStyle.Box);
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.CustomLabels.Add(start, half, "Day 1", 1, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.CustomLabels.Add(half, end, "Day 2", 1, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);
```